# getting Call was rejected by callee exception in VSTO ( Word Application )

Tags: c#-4.0, ms-word, vsto

It's been 3 days that I'm fooling around VSTO (Word application)

I want to create a report in a word document. I already set some bookmarks in the template document.
so my application just opens the template document and search for the each bookmark and replace the bookmark with a table or text in the word document.

I open the word like :

```
application = new Application
                              {
                                  DisplayAlerts = false,
                                  WindowState = WdWindowState.wdWindowStateMaximize,
                                  Visible = false,
                                  CheckLanguage = false,
                                  DisplayAlerts = WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone,
                                  ScreenUpdating = true,
                              };

CurrentDocument = application.Documents.Open(templateFilePath, false, false, false);
```

however, after some inserts, when application is looking for other bookmarks via :

```
if (!CurrentDocument.Bookmarks.Exists(bookmarkTitle))
                return;
```

I get the following exception :

**Call was rejected by callee. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010001 (RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED))**

Any idea how to get rid of it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: It is a lousy low-level error code.  Usually triggered if Word is very busy and can't find the time to handle your call.  If you use any threads in your code then that could cause it.  A lousy workaround is to catch it, sleep for a while and try again.

Comment: I turned off time consuming features. They were the problem! :-)

Comment: I've found this also happens when programmatic UI-affecting actions occur while a modal dialog box is displayed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I turned off these features of word :

```
    CurrentDocument.ShowGrammaticalErrors = false;
    CurrentDocument.ShowRevisions = false;
    CurrentDocument.ShowSpellingErrors = false;
```

**now it's working perfectly**

Comment: Is there a reason all of your `CurrentDocument` calls are misspelled as `CurrentDocuemtn`? (in both the selected answer and the question) Might cause someone a small headache if they copy/paste any of the code.

Comment: thanks for pointing out. A programmer is supposed not to copy/paste any code though. or at least not get into trouble with this kinda mistakes! :-)

Comment: I had the same issue. After finding this page, and then closing down my project, I had a message box on my desktop informing me that there were too many spelling errors in the document to continue to be displayed. Thanks for that catch!

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem when my office became un-activated; and each time when I launch Word I was presented dialogue window about activation failure. As soon as I activated Office, this window no longer appeared and my app worked as usual.