# How to iterate through each word, ms-word?

Tags: c#, loops, ms-word, edit

Ok, my main objective is to go through each word and check if word is underlined.
If it is, I want to change the font size to an int x.

I have tried simply going through each character like so
Edit: Updated code

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        word.Application page = new word.Application();
        page.Visible = true;
        word.Document doc = null;
        foreach (string fi in listBox1.Items)
        {
            doc = page.Documents.Open(Application.StartupPath + "\\old\\" + fi);
            if (doc != null)
            {
                int start = 0;
                foreach (string text in doc.Range().Text.Split(" \r\n\t.".ToCharArray()))
                {
                    int x = doc.Range().Text.IndexOf(text, start);
                    if (doc.Range(x, text.Length - 1).Underline == word.WdUnderline.wdUnderlineSingle)
                        doc.Range(x, text.Length - 1).Font = new word.Font() { Name = "Times New Roman", Bold = 4, Size = 12 };
                    else
                        doc.Range(x, text.Length - 1).Font = new word.Font() { Name = "Times New Roman", Size = 8 };
                    start = x+text.Length;
                }
            }
        }
        //doc.Save();
        // doc.Close();
        // page.Quit();
    }
```

But, I get this error

> Call was rejected by callee. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010001
>   (RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED))

I have no idea why it gives that

Comment: Not able to replicate your conditions; but perhaps this link might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747844/getting-call-was-rejected-by-callee-exception-in-vsto-word-application

Comment: I thank you for your help, but I have been getting really close to my answer now. It loops through the words, but I am currently testing it on a 28 page document so it will take time to see results.

Comment: Happy to read that. If you understand better the exact problem/solution, update your question accordingly (even might want to write your own answer). If it was just something related to not iterating through the ranges properly (not strictly related to Word automation) which might not be too helpful to others, you can just delete this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code could be improved upon heavily:

```
doc = page.Documents.Open(System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "old", fi));
if (doc != null)
{
     word.Font RegularFont = new word.Font() { Name = "Times New Roman", Size = 12 };
     word.Font BigFont = new word.Font() { Name = "Times New Roman", Size = 8 };

     for (int x = 1; x <= doc.Words.Count; x++)
     {
          if (doc.Words[x].Underline != word.WdUnderline.wdUnderlineNone && doc.Words[x].Underline != word.WdUnderline.wdUnderlineDouble)
               doc.Words[x].Font = RegularFont;
           else
                doc.Words[x].Font = BigFont;
      }
}
```

Comment: Yeah my answer is a bit outdated; I switched over to a word.Font[] array instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
             doc = page.Documents.Open(Application.StartupPath + "\\old\\" + fi);
            if (doc != null)
            {
                for (int x = 1; x <= doc.Words.Count - 1; x++)
                {
                        if (doc.Words[x].Underline != word.WdUnderline.wdUnderlineNone && doc.Words[x].Underline != word.WdUnderline.wdUnderlineDouble)
                            doc.Words[x].Font = new word.Font() { Name = "Times New Roman", Bold = 4, Size = 12 };
                        else
                            doc.Words[x].Font = new word.Font() { Name = "Times New Roman", Size = 8 };
                }
```

It works beautifully, but the only problem is that popups prevent the code from continuing

Comment: What does the popup say and which line brings it up?

Comment: BTW, you should really consider creating the font objects OUTSIDE the loop.

Comment: It was just saying that I needed to activate ms word, but I found a fix for that.
I surrounded it with a for loop and a try{ } catch{} loop to give the person some time to exit the popup.